# Looking for a multiple way of entering data in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

What I want to accomplish,

I have a log containing three columns with values (distances),

```
  monday               20x     6,66
  tuesday              20x     6,66
  wednesday            21x     6,9993
  ...
  monday                       6,2
  tuesday              20x     6,666
  ... and so on...
```

In a lot of cases, the value in the rightmost column is a multitude of 0,3333. Is there a way to enable entering of those values in two ways,
a) if a value is entered as "20x" then the column to the right will automatically show 6,66
b) but if there is no value in second column, then you can enter a value manually in the rightmost column

I wish to avoid using an ***"IF Is there a value in the second column approach - if there is, multiply - if there isn't, show a blank"*** approach in the third column, so am looking for alternative approaches.

Is there a way this could be done via cell validation, perhaps?

Grateful for any idea which you might think it might work !

Comment: A VBA Worksheet_Change function maybe? https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/213612

Comment: You would need vba in an Worksheet Change event.  If you have a formula in the cell and someone overwrites the formula it is gone.

Comment: "I wish to avoid using an "IF Is there a value in the second column approach - if there is, multiply - if there isn't, show a blank" approach in the third column, so am looking for alternative approaches." Ok, but why? That's exactly how you should be doing this.

Comment: @airstrike - The content of the cells is exported via a custom library, and having formulas in that column screws it up. I can't tell you why at this point. I mean, I would but I don't know why. :(

Comment: @Rook I see... For the record, I think figuring that out may be better than implementing a Worksheet_Change event as these are a beast to maintain and slow everything down considerably...

Comment: What you desire is a program. If you don't want to use a formula, then you have to write a VB script specific to your needs and there are literally a thousand ways to do that. As aristrike commented, one of those ways is Worksheet_Change event. That is one possible solution. You could create a Macro. How and what the syntax will be is an algorithm that you invent. I've used validation and understand its use and will let you know that you've manually entered wrong data or not, but won't consider a formula. The fact that you mention cell validation leads me to believe you know how it works.